# What's this persistent Camera-app notification in Android 6.0?

Tags: notifications, camera, 6.0-marshmallow

I've been using my Nexus 5X for about a week now, but this morning was the first time I noticed the following notification:

[image: Persistent Camera-app notification]

Backstory: I snapped a few photos this morning (w/ default camera app). Looking at their meta data, they were taken at the exact time it shows in the notification. These are *not* the first photos I've taken with this phone. I don't remember the notification popping up immediately, but I did put away my phone right after taking those photos. Based on the timestamp, I may have simply missed it. I didn't notice the notification until after arriving at the office (roughly 1h 15m later).

Tapping on the notification shows the familiar ripple effect, but nothing happens. It's also persistent: I cannot dismiss it by swiping it.

The notification appears to display some sort of progress, but whatever it was processing, it no longer is. It's about 10am now, and it's still 'stuck' at the same place. The ellipsis seems to suggest that there could be text below the progress bar, but not sure what it would display.

So, does anyone know what this notification's purpose is? And what exactly got stuck while being processed? As a bonus, I'd like to know how to 'continue' whatever got stuck. If continuing isn't an option, then a way to dismiss it without rebooting the phone will also do. I've already tried killing the Camera app, with no result.

Comment: Go to Settings -> Apps -> All apps -> your camera app -> uncheck Show notifications -> agree -> check Show notifications. That should remove any notification of the app. (The method is not tested on Android M but works for Android L and below.)

Comment: @Firelord: On Marshmallow it's just a toggle button called "Block all" (and you don't have to agree to anything first). Enabling and disabling it indeed got rid of the notification. I'd still like to know what it's about though. Thanks so far. :)

Comment: Good to hear that. As per the answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47584/96277), OS simply hides the notification for the app. Technically, your app will continue to push the notifications as usual but OS won't show them to you. As for the cause of the notification, are you using Google Camera app? More specifically, did you use lens blur feature before putting away the phone?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. I just hope the photos aren't syncing with any Google Cloud services.

Comment: @RaymondChenon: Unfortunately l haven't gotten any closer to solving this mystery. The main reason for this is that I haven't seen this notification anymore since posting this. As far as I can tell, I don't seem to be missing any photos (either on my phone or on my synced Google Photos).

Comment: @MH. no changes in my Google Photos too.  BUT I always see this notification lately when I am outside without wifi. So I suspect something is uploading. Did you  "Block all"  notifications ?!?

Comment: @RaymondChenon: Nope, notifications are enabled. I only toggled the setting once to get rid of the notification. It hasn't shown up since. When you say you're walking outside without WiFi, do you mean there is no data connection at all, or with mobile data enabled? In my case it's the latter, although syncing is enabled on WiFi only.

Comment: @MH. in my case mobile data is enabled. However when mobile data is enabled and I am back indoor ( with wifi ), this persistent notification will disappear hours later.

Answer (score 0):

Android M (nexus 5, 6.0.1, security patch 1 juin 2016):

long press the notification, click the (i) button. turn on "block all", then turn off "block all".

This will dismiss the persistent notification.

thanks @Firelord.

ps: I cannot comment or vote on this SE, so I posted an answer.